# Rigify pose selectable but not moveable, or able to drag with cursor

Tags: rigging, armature, error, rigify, pose-mode

After parenting rig with the object mesh, and then going into pose mode, I can select the different pose areas. However, after after right clicking then holding to move/grab the pose area, the pose will not move. In tutorials, it seems that a move/grab icon is supposed to appear by clicking and holding/dragging the selection. When I click and hold to grab the pose area, only a temporary selection box appears.

The only way I can move the pose is to use <kbd>Right Click</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. This also distorts and stretches the figure beyond its shape and length (as shown in the photo). I want the pose to only move the figure by its natural shape.

How do I move the rigify pose normally by grabbing the pose areas without using the move/grab key, <kbd>G</kbd>?

[image]

Here's the file: [image]

Comment: In your image you just have the top-left selection icon selected so you will need to use the hot keys to actually move the rig and model whereas you have the Move icon and gizmo activated in the 3D view in your Blend file and just clicking on it and dragging moves the selected rig widget and limb correctly as expected. Just because the model has a natural shape, it doesn't mean that you can't move the rig further to distort it as you've demonstrated in your image.

Answer (score 0):

In order to click and drag, you have to set the main selection tool to the "Tweak" option.

[image]

When using  a Rigify Rig, in order to have your mesh undeformed you have to lower the "IK Stretch" Slider for every chain of limb.

In my example, I moved only the Torso Control Bone, with Arms IK Stretch turned off to 0 and legs with IK Stretch to 1.0.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!! This is exactly what I needed help with. Thank you for the teaching moment! Thank you, everyone.